# I want to use more elegant construction

Tags: c#

I am not senior at C#, so probably I should learn more basic, but here is my code:

```
var out1 = obj1.F1();
var out2 = obj2.F2(out1);
var out3 = obj3.F3(out2);
var out4 = obj4.F4(out3);
```

Other way is to do the same in one line:

```
var out4 = obj4.F4( obj3.F3( obj2.F2( obj1.F1()  ) ) );
```

But it's difficult to read, more hierarchically, reminds xml tags

So I want to make it more functional. It should look like 'pipeline', 'conveyor' where out of one function is input of other. My solution (with crutches):

```
var obj = new[]{0}; //first looking bad thing, without that you are operating with each element of F1() result
var something = obj
       .Select(x => obj1.F1() ) //second: x=>  x doesn't take part in right side
       .Select(x => obj2.F2(x) )
       .Select(x => obj3.F3(x) )
       .Select(x => obj4.F4(x) )
       .ToArray(); //third: without that it doesn't do anything
```

How should you code this 'pattern'?

Comment: Go look into the [Fluent pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: need more detail. what are you using obj1.F1() for?? chances are it could be done in another way

Comment: this sounds like a violation of the law of Demeter.

Comment: After reading this for a bit, I think the problem may simply lie in what object owns the methods. I'd try moving the method from `obj1`'s type to `out1`'s type.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is much more suitable for such kind of questions.
[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use `Enumerable.Select`, which is designed for sequences (which is not what you have) you can simply create an operator that performs the same operation on individual items:

```
public static TResult Map<TSource, TResult>(
    this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    return selector(source);
}
```

You can then use that without the awkward transformations to/from a sequence:

```
var result = obj1.F1()
    .Map(x => obj2.F2(x))
    .Map(x => obj3.F3(x))
    .Map(x => obj4.F4(x));
```

Comment: That looks great. And I know it's more difficult to debug, but also more expressive

Comment: Probably a bit absurd, but I also created static method BeginPipe() that return new object(), so usage is: var result = BeginPipe().Pipe( x => obj.F1()).Pipe( x => obj2.F2(x) ) ....

Comment: @JamesBrolin Why?  What does it give you?  Why would you not just do what I did here?

Comment: 'A bit absurd' my edition I mean. Sorry. Enter made a comment instead new line

Comment: Your solution fits at all. That is just my thoughts, how to get it more "functional" and uniform, ok?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var result = obj1.F1().Pipe(obj2.F2).Pipe(obj3.F3).Pipe(obj4.F4);
```

(using the following extension method)

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static TOut Pipe<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> func)
    {
        return func(input);
    }
}
```

Not sure it's really more readable, though...

Comment: Good to see you using methodgroups. It's the same as Servy's answer apart from that, though.

Comment: Your extension is the same as Servy's, but his example looks more readable

Comment: @JamesBrolin, well, I find mine more readable, but I guess it's a matter of personal preference ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I don't think many people are familiar with method group syntax. I rarely see it, even when it's clearly applicable. You could probably make some kind of argument that 'now you don't know if it takes a delegate or a variable' - but I don't buy that. It's quite simple once you've taken the time to learn it.

Comment: @JamesBrolin, think of it as shell commands: `obj1.F1() | obj2.F2 | obj3.F3 | obj4.F4`

Comment: Tom, you are right it's matter of habit. Now I find that more 'shelly'. Thanks both

Comment: I don't know, if you wanted to use shell commands in c#, why not just write everything in shell? I don't think these kinds of extensions are very readable, and it completely breaks SOLID.

Comment: @CBauer, it was just an analogy... Anyway, whether you like it or not, it seems to be what the OP was looking for; I wouldn't use it myself either ;). BTW, which of the SOLID principles does it break?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your example is a little poor because I can't tell what exactly these methods are doing. They aren't named anything that infers their purpose, so we can't really give you much advice on how to proceed.

For instance, lets say that this was an image processing library and you were doing something like:

(this is psuedocode)

```
var img = new Image();
var trimmedImage = TrimWhitespace(img);
var rotatedImage = RotateImage(trimmedImage);
var zoomedImage = ZoomImage(rotatedImage);
```

I would still never chain them, but if I needed to reuse it in a presentation layer format, I'd setup an object that orchestrates it, ie:

```
var formattedImage = ImageFormatter.Format(new Image());
```

and ImageFormatter would call them in the order outlined in the psuedocode.

Comment: If possible in a situation like this, I'd include the `TrimWhitespace`, `Rotate`, and `Zoom` methods in `Image`, and have them return the new image. That would allow chaining or this syntax, though your code differs from the question in that four instances are being operated on there.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted, you could always write them as extension methods on image, but I tend to avoid extension methods because they aren't (imho) clear.

Comment: Maybe, but I think you're confusing your own suggestion with reality. These are arbitrary classes, presumably ones he has control over. It does not need to be done with extension methods in that case.

Comment: I think you're the one who is confused. OP didn't provide us with any details about what the output of obj1.F1() is. It could be a string for all you know. You've made a wild assumption about his implementation. He's asking about an indeterminate pattern doing indeterminate things to indeterminate objects. I think the safest assumption is that he's mutating a CLR class.